# How to apply pagination in laravel Searchy extension

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I have implemented an extension in my laravel application called - https://github.com/livelyworks/Laravel-Searchy

Here I am unable to apply paginate.

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -]/', '', $query);
$searchdata = Searchy::search('snippets')
  ->fields('snippets_name', 'seo_description','snippets_description','snippet_tags')
  ->query($str)
  ->getQuery()
  ->limit(20)
  ->get();
```

Comment: you cant `limit` and `paginate` together

Answer (score 0):

add ->offset(0) after ->limit() for page 1. next page : offset + limit, prev page : offset - limit.

assuming $page is 1 for the first page and 2 for the second page:

```php
$offset = 20 * ($page??1 - 1)
$searchdata = Searchy::search('snippets')->fields('snippets_name', 'seo_description','snippets_description','snippet_tags')->query($str)
->getQuery()->limit(20)->offset($offset)->get();
```

update :

if you want to use pagination query builder :

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -]/', '', $query);
$searchdata = Searchy::search('snippets')
  ->fields('snippets_name', 'seo_description','snippets_description','snippet_tags')
  ->query($str)
  ->getQuery()
  ->paginate(20);
```

in view

```
@foreach($searchdata as $data)
    // show data
@endforeach

{{ $searchdata->links() }}
```

url :

your_url/1
your_url/2
your_url/3
...

but if you want to use query limit :

```
public function your_function_page($page=1) {

    $limit = 20;
    $offset = $limit * ( $page > 0 ? $page - 1 : 0 );

    $str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -]/', '', $query);
    
    $query = Searchy::search('snippets')->fields('snippets_name', 'seo_description','snippets_description','snippet_tags')
                        ->query($str);

    $searchdata = $query->getQuery()
                        ->limit($limit)
                        ->offset($offset)
                        ->get();

    $total_data = $query->get()
                        ->count();

    $total_page = ceil( $total_data / $limit );

    $link_pagination = 'url';
    $pagination = collect();
    for ($i=0; $i < $total_page ; $i++) { 
        $numb = $i + 1; 
        $link = $link_pagination . '/' . $numb;
        $pagination[] = '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $numb . '</a>';
    }
    $pagination = $pagination->join(" ");

    return view('your_page_data')
            ->with('searchdata', $searchdata)
            ->with('pagination', $pagination);

}
```

in view :

```
@foreach($searchdata as $data)
    // show data
@endforeach

{{ $pagination }}
```

url :

your_url/1
your_url/2
your_url/3
...

Comment: have you tried, ->offset(0), ->offset(20), ->offset(40), ...

Comment: Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist.  getting this

Comment: Now how to declare it in blade.php file, it seems I am getting above because of that. {{$search_results->links()}}

Comment: Getting same results on every page

Comment: same result for pagination query builder or query limit offset?

Comment: query builder is not working. did it for query limit offset

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$searchdata = Searchy::search('snippets')
        ->fields('snippets_name', 'seo_description','snippets_description','snippet_tags')
        ->query($str)
        ->getQuery()
        ->take($numPerPage)
        ->get();
```

Comment: How to get pagination in blade.php